# OkHttp Api call to Okta Api end point hits {"successful":true,"redirect":false} instead of actual dataset

Tags: okhttp, okta

I am attempting to call okta to get the user info API endpoint with the Okhttp library. The application received {"successful": true,"redirect": false} when the call from java spring boot, instead of the actual dataset from the API endpoint using Postman. What am i missing in this case:

```
                Request requestValue = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://dev-xxxxxxx.okta.com/api/v1/users/xxxxxx")
                        .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "SSWS " + apiKey.getCfgValue()).build();
                
                try (Response response = httpClient.newCall(requestValue).execute()) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        return response;
                    }
                }
```

Appreciate much that anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response response = httpClient.newCall(requestValue).execute()
**response.body()**
```

That's what you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).